# Alternate If-Else Block in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have got a code which if,unless block a number of times like this:

Option is hashmap.

```
unless functioncall? options[:product]
    puts "Hello wrold"
end
```

Can anyone explain the flow of this unless block. I am new to ruby and I use curly braces block in place of this.

Comment: it's exactly like `if`, but, well, reverse. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that I know, what i want to know is that what the flow is like, what is the condition statement here? what is the use options[:product] here, is it a argument to the function call?

Comment: Yes, it's the argument to a function call. Read like this `unless functioncall?(options[:product])`

Comment: Hah, good old "Hello wrold".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### translation to if-syntax

In `if` syntax, this is equivalent to:

```
if functioncall?(options[:product])
else
  puts "Hello World"
end
```

OR

```
if !functioncall?(options[:product])
  puts "Hello World"
end
```

### Output of boolean method

The method `functioncall?(options[:product])` will return true if the options hash has a key called `product`.

### Output of your method

Depending on the contents of the options hash, the method above will produce:

```
# options = { :key => value, :product => 'stuff'}
functioncall?(options[:product]) #=> true
# the output of your code would be nil

# options = { :key => value, :foo => 'bar'}
functioncall?(options[:product]) #=> false
# the output of your code would be "Hello World"
```

Comment: Actually, it is not equivalent. The OP's code prints `Hello wrold`, not `Hello World`. Don't worry. You are not wrong. I would rather want what you have than what OP has. I voted down the question for its sloppiness.